# Is there a common way to create sliding sub-views in a list?

Tags: android, jquery, layout, android-studio, uislider

The idea isn't very complicated, and I'm pretty sure I've seen it before, the following image illustrates the idea:

[See this picture since it won't let me embed yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOoHM.png)

I figure this would be a pretty common thing, but I just don't know what it is called.

I have found some information just by doing some searching, but most are from pull up menus from the bottom of the screen etc. I can figure out how to get something to "slide" out, but not really sure how to push everything else down.

Not looking for someone to code this for me, just some pointers.

Comment: use expandable list view : http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you want to implement expandable list view. so please view this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) .